# Having a SOAP web service interact with a REST API?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, soap, google-api

I am just learning about what a web service is and how to use one, so bear with me if this is a stupid question.

I am making an Android app and will be trying to use a service account for server-to-server interactions between the [Google Play Android Developer API (REST)](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started), and [my web service (SOAP)](http://iphone.e-imo.com/IMOTPWS.asmx?op=Search).  Is this a problem? What do I need to know to get started with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, SOAP and REST are like Chinese and English.  They are so different they can't talk to each other without something to translate between them.  Though they both can do XML, it's just not the same at all.

Comment: So does that mean that this is doable with "translation"? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: REST is about requesting and modifying data (stored within an object/resource).

SOAP is about asking objects/resources to perform some action on the data it holds.

Comment: What you're going to need to do is write some code that reads from one service into some java object format (both SOAP and REST have libraries for this) then translates that java object and writes to the other web service.  Your question is too general for me to go into much detail.  But consider technologies like Jersey or RestEasy for REST; and Metro or Axis for SOAP.  It really depends on the stack you've got.  Glassfish works easily with Metro and Jersey, and JBoss works easily with RestEasy, for example.  All of them can technically be used in any server/container.

Comment: Short version: Android calls Google Play API, converts data and makes a SOAP call to your service, but it really depends on a lot of things I don't know about your project.

Comment: I'll just keep blathering on, but a friend of mine wrote a game on android and talks to his glassfish server over soap with it.  He also does in app purchases in the game.  That sounds something like what you are doing.